# Solr indexing Model class

Tags: spring, solr, solr4

I am new to solr.I am trying to add data to solr .I have class Education with properties and getter/setter methods. I am trying to add field to solr List. What should be field type in schema.xml ?

```
<field name="education"      type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Actually it's not clear what you are looking for. It'll be really helpful if you post more information about your project. 
Any way, Education is a class in your application. You might not need to declare its type in schema.xml. I guess you might need to define properties of your class in your schema with relevant field type.

Comment: This question is very generic and is not really possible to answer it